# How to print output with spaces in between each number

Tags: python

My code runs fine but I would like for each number to have a space between each number

```
string = input()
newstring = "".join(c for c in string if c.isalpha())
def alphabet(newstring):
    dict = {'a':'1','b':'2','c':'3','d':'4','e':'5','f':'6','g':'7','h':'8','i':'9','j':'10','k':'11','l':'12','m':'13','n':'14','o':'15','p':'16','q':'17','r':'18','s':'19','t':'20','u':'21','v':'22','w':'23','x':'24','y':'25','z':'26'}
    new = newstring.lower()
    for i in (new):
        if i in dict:
            new = new.replace(i, dict[i])
    return new
print(alphabet(newstring))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use keyword arguments in the print statement like this:

```py
...
print(*alphabet(newstring), sep=" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can add space to be appended with dict[i]
like

```
new = new.replace(i, dict[i]+" ")
```

Comment: The code grader says my output is wrong because an additional space is added after the last number. any suggestions on how to delete the final space?

Comment: try adding .rstrip() in print like  print(alphabet(newstring) .rstrip())